# Bubbling componentWillUpdate and componentDidUpdate

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs, react-dom

I know this is not idiomatic React, but I'm working on a React component (an inverse scrollview) which needs to get notified of downstream virtual DOM changes both before they are rendered and after they are rendered.

This is a little hard to explain so I made a JSFiddle with a starting point: https://jsfiddle.net/7hwtxdap/2/

My goal is to have the log look like:

```
Begin log

render

rendered small

rendered small

rendered small

before update

rendered big

after update

before update

rendered big

after update

before update

rendered big

after update
```

I'm aware that React sometimes batches DOM changes and that's fine (i.e. the log events could be `before update; rendered big; rendered big; after update; ...`) -- important part is that I am actually notified before and after the DOM changes.

---

I can manually approximate the behavior by specifying callbacks, as done here: https://jsfiddle.net/7hwtxdap/4/. However, this approach does not scale—I need, for example, to have events bubble from descendents rather than children; and would rather not have to add these kind of event handlers to *every* component I use.

---

Use case:

I'm working on making an "inverted scrolling component" for messages (where, when new elements are added or existing elements change size, the basis for scroll change is from the bottom of the content rather than the top ala every messaging app) which has dynamically modified children (similar to the `<MyElement />` class but with variable height, data from ajax, etc). These are not getting data from a Flux-like state store but rather using a pub-sub data sync model (approximated pretty well with the setTimeout()).

To make inverse scrolling work, you need to do something like this:

```
anyChildrenOfComponentWillUpdate() {
  let m = this.refs.x;
  this.scrollBottom = m.scrollHeight - m.scrollTop - m.offsetHeight;
}
anyChildrenOfComponentDidUpdate() {
  let m = this.refs.x;
  m.scrollTop = m.scrollHeight - m.offsetHeight - this.scrollBottom;
}
```

Importantly to this design, I'd like to be able to wrap the element around other elements that are not "inverted scrolling aware" (i.e. do not have to have special code to notify the inverted scrolling handler that they have changed).

Comment: What about componentWillMount and componentDidUpdate lifecycle methods ?

Comment: Those also do not "bubble" up to parents.

Comment: How are you managing state? Are you using redux or anything like that? Also, why exactly do you need to know when children update? It might help if you explained what you'll do with that info. There might be a different way to handle that.

Comment: Hi @dannyid, let me know if that helps.

Comment: Did you take a look to [react-waypoint](https://github.com/brigade/react-waypoint). I do know that it's not the exact use case you have but it might inspired you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know what the best solution is to your problem without knowing why you need this functionality.  However, I'll address this specific point:

> I need, for example, to have events bubble from descendents rather than children; and would rather not have to add these kind of event handlers to every component I use.

I would suggest two changes to your solution for this.  The first is to consider using [context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html), but make sure to read the warnings before deciding to do so.  This will allow you to define your callbacks in a single component and have them instantly available in all descendants.

The second change would be to move all your logging logic into a separate component, and have other components inherit it as needed.  This component would look something like:

```
class LoggingComponent extends React.Component {
  componentWillUpdate() {
    if (this.context.onWillUpdate) {
        this.context.onWillUpdate();
    }
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.context.onDidUpdate) {
        this.context.onDidUpdate();
    }
  }
}

LoggingComponent.contextTypes = {
    onWillUpdate: React.PropTypes.func,
    onDidUpdate: React.PropTypes.func
};
```

This way, you can easily add this functionality to new components without duplicating the logic.  I've updated your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7hwtxdap/6/) with a working demo.

Comment: Thanks James. It may be that using context with the extended class is the cleanest way to do this—although forcing all downstream classes to inherit from a particular class is still not great. I've also updated the question above with some more specific context to see if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

React, by design, respects that a `setState` call on a component should trigger a re-rendering of `that` component. The most reliable way I know of to hook onto a component's life-cycle is on the component itself.

How about you pass down a `notifier()` callback as a prop and then call this function within the `componentWillMount` and `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle hook of the children components?

[Here's a working js-fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7hwtxdap/5/) with this idea. Let me know what comes up.

**Edit 1**

If you'd rather not pass callbacks back and forth through every single child component, then I'd say you've just come across a specific use case of `Redux` and `Flux`.

With Redux, a component can, through a reducer function, change the state of a store. Every component watching for a change in that store is then re-rendered. `Flux` uses the same idea.

So I'd suggest you use redux to handle state setting. To get started, you could go through [these tutorial videos](https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux) by redux's creator, Dan Abramov.

Comment: Hi Cent, you can see that I've actually done something like this in the second JSFiddle -- trying to avoid passing callbacks everywhere !

Comment: You're right @AaronYodaiken I just edited my answer to take on your specific preferences. Redux/Flux is the way to go then, my friend :)

Comment: Cent, redux is great but here it isn't quite the right solution — my scroll container should not need to know which paths the things inside it are depending on (this breaks encapsulation !)

Comment: @AaronYodaiken Using Redux in this specific case doesn't say you expose states and properties to component that don't need to know them. What I highlighted was that with Redux your child component (the individual messages) can broadcast that they have changed, so that the scroll container knows to re-render. This way, no rule of encapsulation is broken. I could be missing something though. Can you update your jsfiddle with a mock close to what you currently have?

Comment: what I meant was that the scrolling container is fundamentally listening to *dom* changes -- that is the contract -- it should not care about app data; child components should not need to update it, and so on. This is a weird use case for React, I know.

Answer (score 1):

As James said, you can use context to define a callback function which you can pass down to all descendant components and if you don't want to extend your components you can use a decorator to wrap a Higher order component around them. Something like this:

In your container:

```
class Container extends React.Component {
    static childContextTypes =  {
        log: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
    };

   getChildContext() {
      return {
            log: (msg) => {
                console.log(msg)
            }
        }
    }

  render() {
    console.log("Begin Log")
    return (
        <div>
          <MyElement />
          <MyElement />
          <MyElement />
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The decorator class:

```
export const Logger = ComposedComponent => class extends React.Component {
    static contextTypes = {
        log: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.context.log('will receive props');
    }

    componentWillUpdate() {
        this.context.log('before update');
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        this.context.log('after update');
    }

  render() {
      return <ComposedComponent {...this.props}/>
  }
}
```

Then decorate the components you want

```
@Logger
class MyElement extends React.Component {
...
}
```

Comment: Hi I don't think that this will work, since the `ComposedComponent` is what is recieving the update events, not the wrapped/decorator component.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have a look to [react-virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/reverseList.md) which has an exemple for reverse scroll list.

> ```
> export default class Example extends Component {
>   constructor (props) {
>     super(props)
>
>     this.state = {
>       list: []
>     }
>   }
>
>   componentDidMount () {
>     this._interval = setInterval(::this._updateFeed, 500)
>   }
>
>   componentWillUnmount () {
>     clearInterval(this._interval)
>   }
>
>   render () {
>     const { list } = this.state
>
>     return (
>       <div className={styles.VirtualScrollExample}>
>         <VirtualScroll
>           ref='VirtualScroll'
>           className={styles.VirtualScroll}
>           width={300}
>           height={200}
>           rowHeight={60}
>           rowCount={list.length}
>           rowRenderer={::this._rowRenderer}
>         />
>       </div>
>     )
>   }
>
>   _updateFeed () {
>     const list = [ ...this.state.list ]
>
>     list.unshift(
>       // Add new item here
>     )
>
>     this.setState({ list })
>
>     // If you want to scroll to the top you can do it like this
>     this.refs.VirtualScroll.scrollToRow(0)
>   }
>
>   _rowRenderer (index) {
>     return (
>       // Your markup goes here
>     )
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: What react-virtualized is doing is relying on a static `rowHeight`; which means that it does not need to listen for DOM changes.